# PROPFIND not supported WAS 8.5

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, websphere, webdav

My colleague gets the below trace in Websphere 8.5.5 when downloading a generated spreadsheet to the browser.  Some googling shows this is related to something called "WebDAV", but we're just trying to download a spreadsheet.  The download still succeeds, but we don't want this to go to production and clutter up the logs (currently he's working in RAD with WAS locally).

Does anyone know how one suppresses this message (since the feature does actually work) or better yet, if there is some method of supplying the spreadsheet that won't trigger it at all?

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: Method PROPFIND is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API 
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:626)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:656)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1301)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't influence to performance. BTW, to get rid of this error try

1.change httpd.conf of IHS like below

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^PROPFIND 
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

- Dont forget to restart IHS

2.Compile you code with newer versions of lib, for example use commons-io-1.4.jar, comons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar etc